# Realm + RxJava + Android : Saving Realm object using RxJava in Android

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to figure out how to save Realm Object in Realm using RxJava in android. So far all the example combining all of these are how to read data from Realm. 
I want to to save data to Realm using RxJava in android. Can any one point me into the right direction.

Comment: https://github.com/viraj49/Realm_android-injection-rx-test

Comment: Thanks Viraj. It was good source of information , but it still doesn't solve my problem. I want to handle transaction in Realm while keeping track of error and success as well. And in case of error I want the Observer to perform some action.

Comment: Use beginTransaction, commitTransaction and cancelTransaction combo. throw custom error code using observalble.just(cutomErrorCode).

Comment: Thanks. that was helpful. In  my mind I thought RX might have some other way of doing these things. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Subscription loadObjectsFromNetwork() {
    return objectApi.getObjects()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(response -> {
            try(Realm realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                realmInstance.executeTransaction(realm -> realm.insertOrUpdate(response.objects));
            }
        });
}
```